# What car safety equipment is mandatory in Czech Republic? Do I need to carry spare tires?

Tags: safety, automobiles, czech-republic

Is spare tire (full size or temporary) mandatory in Czech Republic?
I wonder if any tire would fit in my cars trunk. Right now, I only possess tire patch kit. I drive hatchback.

Comment: I'm familiar with some cars that don't accommodate a spare tire and only come with a patch kit and run-flats, so I'm not sure how such a rule would work unless those cars are literally banned in the Czech Republic. In any case, [this article](http://www.theaa.com/motoring_advice/touring_tips/czech-republic.pdf) from The AA doesn't mention any such requirement, but a local may be able to provide better advice here.

Comment: I've made the question a bit more broad, hope you don't mind.

Comment: Not at all, but I wonder if removing "spare tire" phrase in title won't make it harder to find this question.

Comment: Good thinking. I've combined the two titles :)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Assuming you're driving a regular passenger car, the [list of mandatory equipment](https://cs.wikipedia.org/wiki/Povinn%C3%A1_v%C3%BDbava_motorov%C3%A9ho_vozidla) (Czech wiki link) for Czech Republic is:

- Spare [spark plugs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spark_plug)
- Spare light bulbs
- [Car jack](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jack_(device))
- Wrenches
- Spare tire (or tire patch kit, if the tire is patchable; or neither, for [run-flat tyres](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Run-flat_tire))
- Medical kit
- Emergency warning triangle
- Reflective vest

So **no**, you won't need a spare tire. The maximum fine for violating this law is 2000 CZK (~75 EUR), however the police rarely checks passenger cars for compliance.

Comment: Spare **spark plugs** are not required, from the wikipedia list you mentioned "elektrické pojistky" are **spare electric fuses**

Answer (score 5):

According to the [1968 Vienna Convention](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vienna_Convention_on_Road_Traffic) a vehicle is legal to drive in a signatory country if it is legal to drive in its country of registration.

So if your car is legal to drive in your country, and your country has signed the Vienna Convention, <strike>you don't have to worry about local mandatory equipment</strike> you should not be fined for not carrying the local mandatory equipment.

Note that in some situations, *use* of such equipment might be required and that requirement would apply to you.

Comment: Very interesting. So if you don't need to carry a warning triangle, say, in your own country, you don't have to buy one for a country that otherwise requires them? I recall reading the opposite from organisations like the UK AA or RAC

Comment: In theory, you wouldn't need to. The treaty allows you to legally drive the vehicle abroad if it conforms to your country's regulations. In reality, I guess conforming to local rules may save you some unpleasant time. Like when the policeman doesn't know anything about the treaty. Or one article I've read mentions that even if you don't eg. legally need a  high-visibility vest in your car, you'd still be required to wear it when out of the car on highway if local laws say so.

Comment: At least in Spain, you are required to wear the vest if you leave the car; and place the triangles if the car is stopped in a road, so even if they're not needed in practise you'll need to have them.

Comment: I've edited the answer to emphasize the distinction between "carry" and "use".

Comment: I'm not sure this answer is correct, because the driver is still expected to obey the _rules of the road_. It's pretty unambiguous that you have to obey speed limits, you can't claim that your German car can drive at Autobahn speeds even outside Germany. Mandatory equipment is a middle ground. As it's not structurally part of the vehicle, I wonder whether if falls under the vehicle rules or road rules.

Comment: @MSalters Info taken from [Besip's article on traveling abroad by car](http://www.ibesip.cz/cz/ridic/cestujeme-automobilem/vybava-vozidla-pri-ceste-do-zahranici) (article in Czech). Besip is part of Czech Ministry of Transport.

Comment: This is what I wanted to ask, and I also find out that information, that Vienna Convention voids odd requirements of signing parties. For example, in my case having spare bulbs would be a pure nonsense. A pack of them is very expensive for my car, I will be unable to change them myself, and I have very good assistance Europe-wide...